# WiFi slow on laptop

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have an 200Mbps connection, however it is around 50Mbps on my laptop with WiFi even while parked right next to the router. While connecting wired and on our mobile phones we reach the full 200Mbps from further away even. The chip in my laptop is the Intel Wireless-N 7260. On the Intel website it states that it is able to handle 300Mbps. My OS is Windows 10 and the drivers are the latest.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is the router/AP set to 40 MHz or 20 MHz mode? Does the laptop support MIMO? Remember that the marketing numbers practically always are for best possible conditions...

Comment: What band? How crowded is the band where you live? How are you measuring the WiFi speed exactly?

Comment: my laptop is a lenovo yoga 2 and it supports mimo and the router is set to 40 MHZ

Comment: You've got to tell us what your router is capable of, Wi-Fi wise, as well. It might be best to just state the make and model, because we'll need to know things like band capabilities and number of spatial streams. Are you connecting in 2.4GHz or 5GHz? How did you measure that 50Mbps number?